# How to add a column of zeros in a List<List<double[]>>()?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I would like to add a column of zeros to all of my `double[]` in my `List<List<double[]>>()`.

The length of the `double[]` is currently 2 and I would like to have `doubles[]` of length 3. The zero should always be in the third position, for example:

```
double[50, 75] // double [50,75,0]
```

This has to be done in all of the `List<double[]>` within `List<List<double[]>>`.

Is there a short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a short way of doing this in terms of lines of code, but the number of allocations and copying is equal to the number of arrays in the original list:

```
var res = orig.
    Select(list => list
        .Select(array => array.Concat(new[] {0.0}).ToArray())
        .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rVZVvv)

Comment: I think she wants to extend the arrays. if there is another pointer to `orig` this pointer won't make the change. in this case she will has a inconsistent data in her application....

Comment: @OldFox The question is not clear on whether OP wants to make a change to the original or to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

because you want to extend the array in the source list you need to manipulate them in the internal list:

```
        foreach (var list in rootList)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var actor = list[i];
                list[i] = new double[actor.Length + 1]; // all elements will be 0....
                Array.Copy(list[i], actor, actor.Length); //just add the prev elements
            }
        }
```

the above operation will apply the change on all pointers to `List<List<double[]>>`.
if you don't want to make the change on all pointer to `rootList`, @dasblinkenlight answer is good enough.